# How to grab Used ID in ajax post-login response (JWT)?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

hope you're all safe n' sound.  I'm JS noob so I've been reading about 40 questions related to my doubt, with no success.  My issue showed up due to JWT implementation.  Signup, login, update no problem, but after a token has been generated I need a way to identify the current user. So, my question is:

**How can I get the user id in ajax response, so I can assign it to a
working JS variable?**

I get the data as JSON stringified response as follows (console.log):

**{"*data":{"id":"6","firstname":"Edd","lastname":"Lieberflusse","mobile":"900000000"*}}**

Now this is my ajax call:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#checker', function()
{
var checker=$(this);
var form_data=JSON.stringify(checker.serializeObject());
$.ajax({
url: "inner-validator.php",
type : "POST",
contentType : 'application/json',
data : form_data,
success: function(data)
{   
var datum = (JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(datum);
var info = JSON.parse(datum);
console.log(typeof info);
console.log(info.id) ;
console.log(info.firstname) ;
console.log(info.lastname) ;
console.log(info.mobile) ;
}, // end success
error: function(xhr, resp, text){
$('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Some error warning HTTP Code</div>");
} //end error
});
$('#checker').css("display", "none");
return false;
});
```

At runtime, console displays the following:

```
{"data":{"id":"6","firstname":"Edd","lastname":"Lieberflusse","mobile":"900000000"}}
index.php:108 object
index.php:109 undefined
index.php:110 undefined
index.php:111 undefined
index.php:112 undefined
```

Point is I need to assign the ID to a variable, in order to later on insert some user activities in DB via php.  Probably it's so simple, but even with parse/revive I'm just unable to find a way.
Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: Try `console.log(info.data.id)`

Comment: Jesus!  Thank you very much!  Been reading and trying voodoo magic for ages.
It worked like a charm.  Thanks again Eldar.